# restrict user to autowire only interface

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have the following interface

```
public interface MTS{
   public SrvResponse sendMessage(MTSModel msg);
   public SrvResponse sendMessage(MTSModel msg, Type type);
}
```

the implementation

```
@Component
public class MTSImpl implements MTS {...}
```

Can I restrict user to autowire only interface `private @Autowired MTS service;` not `MTSImpl` in spring boot ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I restrict user to autowire only interface private @Autowired MTS
>   service; not MTSImpl in spring boot ?

Spring doesn't provide such restrictions for injections.
As alternative you could "protected" your implementation class from clients by making it `package private` (the default access modifier) in a package that they don't use :

```
package foo.internal;
class MTSImpl implements MTS {
   ...
}
```

Or to hide it completely you could define it as an anonymous class :

```
@Bean
public MTS getMts() {
    return new MTS() {

       @Override
       public SrvResponse sendMessage(MTSModel msg){           
         ...
       }
       @Override
       public SrvResponse sendMessage(MTSModel msg, Type type){
         ...
       }

    };
}
```